# Map data posgtresqsql

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I hope that you are fine,

I want to read csv file thats exists in /home/BNP/File.csv

My file 1 contains 3 columns COL_, COL1, and COL2.
Exemple of data in my

```
SCHOOLAA/Fourniture/pencil, SCHOOL, SCHOOL
HOMEAA/Fourniture/desk, HOME OFFICE, HOME
HOMEAA/Fourniture/,  HOME, FOURNITURE
```

Values of my table **dab** of my database:

```
 id,      COL_

221323, SCHOOL12/Fourniture/pencil

221324, SCHOOL13/Fourniture/pencil

221325, HOME00/Fourniture/desk

221326, SCHOOL14/Fourniture/pencil

221327, HOME01/Fourniture/

221328, HOME04/Fourniture/
```

I want to create table **dabres** that contains Three columns COL_, COL1, COL2.

```
**Result:** 
**COL_                         COL1       COL2**

SCHOOL12/Fourniture/pencil.   , SCHOOL, SCHOOL

SCHOOL13/Fourniture/pencil.   , SCHOOL, SCHOOL

HOME00/Fourniture/desk       ,HOME OFFICE, HOME

SCHOOL14/Fourniture/pencil   ,SCHOOL, SCHOOL

HOME01/Fourniture/         ,HOME, FOURNITURE

HOME04/Fourniture/       ,HOME, FOURNITURE
```

I did an attempt below, how can i do it dynamically while reading the file. Lets notice that my File.csv contains 50 rows so its not too easy to eat case by case.

**CODE**

```
execute $$
INSERT INTO $$||new_table_name||$$
(COL_, COL1, COL2)
SELECT * from (
       (case
            when TRIM(COL_) ~ '^SCHOOL[0-9]{2}/Fourniture/desk/'
            then HOME OFFICE
            when TRIM(COL_) ~ '^SCHOOL[0-9]{2}/Fourniture/pencil/'  
            then 'SCHOOL'
            when TRIM(COL_) ~ '^SCHOOL[0-9]{2}/Fourniture/'  
            then 'HOME'
            else 'NONE'
      end) as COL1,
  (case
            when TRIM(COL_) ~ '^SCHOOL[0-9]{2}/Fourniture/desk/'
            then HOME
            when TRIM(COL_) ~ '^SCHOOL[0-9]{2}/Fourniture/pencil/'  
            then 'SCHOOL'
            when TRIM(COL_) ~ '^SCHOOL[0-9]{2}/Fourniture/'  
            then 'FOURNITURE'
            else 'NONE'
      end) as COL2

 )
```

Best regards,
graciass!!

Comment: Why not just `CREATE TABLE dabres(COL_ varchar,COL1 varchar, COL2 varchar) and then `COPY` the csv into it?

Comment: No maybe i wasn't clear. My file FIL1.txt is just to see what COL1 and COL2 should contains if col_ of dab='VALUE'. Do you see what i mean? Please tell me if im not clear @AdrianKlaver

Comment: No I don't.  You say you want to read or iterate over the 50 rows in `File.csv`. I am not seeing the relationship between `dab` and `dabres` as I see don't see `dab.id` is being used.

Comment: **dabres** Is a new table of **dab** with mapping the new columns. Yes you are right i just forgot to added in my code dab.id. AM i still unclear, ? @AdrianKlaver

Comment: Seems to me the "AA" in the CSV represent some sort of wild-card for joining to `dab` table. Might be easiest to "mask" the digits in `dab` to the wild-card, e.g. load the csv to `dabtemp` and join `ON REGEXP_REPLACE(dab.CSV_,'[0-9]{2}/','AA/')=dabtemp.CSV_`

Comment: i did'nt got you. Can you explain more please?  @Fred thanx

Answer (score 0):

This is untested so do this in a test environment. Also assumes using `psql`:

```
CREATE TABLE dab_col_map("COL_" varchar, "COL1" varchar, "COL2" varchar);

\copy dab_col_map FROM 'File.csv' WITH (CSV);

CREATE TABLE 
   dabres 
AS 
   SELECT 
      dab.id, db."COL_", dab_col_map."COL1", dab_col_map."COL2" 
   FROM 
      dab 
   LEFT JOIN 
      dab_col_map 
   ON 
      dab."COL_" = dab_col_map."COL_";
```

This assumes the column names are actually upper case in the database. If not then you don't need the quoting.

Comment: As @Adrian Klaver said but with `ON REGEXP_REPLACE(dab."COL_",'[0-9]{2}/','AA/')=dab_col_map."COL_"` instead of simple equality. Also `db."_COL"` above should be `dab."COL_"` (minor typo)